# event.stopImmediatePropagation() does not work on Chrome for Android

Tags: android, jquery

I believe `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` does not work on Chrome for Android.
Would anyone have a fix for it ? (alternative code) ?
Thanks.

Comment: I assume `event.stopPropagation()` or adding `return false` at the end of your listener's handler wouldn't suffice?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté that will only stop propagation to parent elements. stopImmediatePropagation() stops to sibling elements too. See http://jsfiddle.net/GkJDF/

Comment: Also prevents the next event handlers bound to the current element from running, I see the difference clearer now. Thanks @ThomasClayson.

Comment: It is likely your code that doesn't work

Comment: This appears to be fixed now. I cannot reproduce it on a fresh install of Chrome on my tablet. ( testing the example on [the jQuery API page for stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) )

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
event.callNonExistingMethode();
```

or

Do not use `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` instead use only `stopImmediatePropagation();`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you're not looking for  `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score -1):

`event.stopImmediatePropagation()` implicit calls `event.stopPropagation()`

Can you please try with `event.stopPropagation()` ?

Comment: event.stopPropagation() is NOT the same thing as event.stopImmediatePropagation().  The latter affects handlers for sibling elements and parent elements; the former only for parent elements.

Comment: @Jeff `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` has nothing to do with sibling elements. Yes it prevents the event from bubbling to parent elements just like `event.stopPropagation()` but also prevents any subsequent event handlers on the same element from firing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: @riscarrott: Your link confirms what Jeff says above, and refutes your statement.

Comment: @Flimzy Yeah that would be true...if it wasn't not true.

Comment: @riscarrott: No skin off my back if you want to ignore the obvious and write buggy code.